# Understanding TCP dynamics

Tags: tcp, timeout

What I am experiencing:
We have an app server that connects to a rabbitmq server.
As time goes on, the number of ESTABLISHED connections looking from the rabbitmq server goes up, but the count from the app server remains fairly constant.

I run this on both:

```
root@app01:~# netstat -ant | grep EST | grep 5672 | grep 172.25.12.48
tcp        0      0 172.25.12.48:50587      10.48.64.230:5672       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 172.25.12.48:50588      10.48.64.230:5672       ESTABLISHED 

root@rabbit01:~# netstat -ant | grep EST | grep 5672 | grep 172.25.12.48
tcp6       0      0 10.48.64.230:5672       172.25.12.48:38408      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 10.48.64.230:5672       172.25.12.48:50588      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 10.48.64.230:5672       172.25.12.48:33491      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 10.48.64.230:5672       172.25.12.48:50587      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 10.48.64.230:5672       172.25.12.48:34541      ESTABLISHED
```

Example results will give say 6 on the app server and 15 (even as high as 46) on the rabbitmq server.
I restart the rabbitmq server and obviously everything is back to normal, 2 connections each side.

I am assuming that either the switch times out the connection or the application terminates the process uncleanly. I am looking into this, but I would like to understand the TCP behaviour better.

Current settings on the rabbitmq server:

tcp_retries1 set to 3
tcp_retries2 set to 15

So I would normally have expected to see those 'invalid' connections drop after around 13-30 minutes if I understand the forums correctly.

Yet, looking at the tcp keepalive values:

tcp_keepalive_time is set to 7200 (So after 2h it will send the first keepalive probe.)
tcp_keepalive_intvl is 75 (So 75 seconds after the first one, it will resend a probe.)
tcp_keepalive_probes is 9 (So it will send 9 probes in total)

So the keepalive process will take 7200+(9*75)=7875, or roughly 2 hours 11 minutes before closing.

Due to the connection (presumably) disappearing, that leads to two questions.
1. Which is correct?
2. Am I missing another option apart from switch or app terminating abnormally  that could cause these invalid connections?

Source: https://www.frozentux.net/ipsysctl-tutorial/chunkyhtml/tcpvariables.html

Comment: It isn't possible for the number of `ESTABLISHED` connections between two hosts to show as different at each host. I suggest you post the relevant parts of the actual `netstat` outputs at both hosts. At present it isn't clear what you're talking about.

Comment: Updated the post to include actual output of netstat.
Up untli a few days ago I would have agreed with your statement 100%!

Comment: I should correct that. It is possible, if one end has reset the connection and the other end doesn't know about that yet.

Comment: Yea, that made sense to me, but the fact that the Checkpoints are keeping that connection valid for days was slightly annoying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our F5's were the reason for this. 
Seems after an idle timeout, the F5 drops the entry from its tables. So from the app servers, the connection is invalid, and TCP closes them. 
From the rabbitmq server though, somehow that connections remains a valid connections. 
Although I don't understand why a switch has the ability to keep a connection state valid - but, this was the reason.